# Find the last 5 digits even when there is a character and convert them to integer

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have to always get the last 5 digits from a string and need to convert it to int.
But I have situations where the 5th digit from the end is a character.
If I have the a character then I want to just get the number.

**Sample data:**

```
Input                  Expected Output
978568-16258            16258 
ERGF99252697            52697
SP-988824-189241        89241
SP-456790-568723        68723
SP-456790-568           568
```

I'have tried some thing like this:

```
select CAST((RIGHT(RTRIM(col_1),5)) AS UNSIGNED INT) as test from table_A;
```

For few of the reults its ok but when it sees characters then it displays a random number.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: mysql/mariadb version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.0.5, you can use `regexp_substr()` for this. This should be as simple as:

```
select cast(regexp_substr(col_1, '[0-9]{1,5}$') as unsigned) from table_A
```

Regexp `'[0-9]{1,5}$'` means: as many digits as possible (maximum 5) at the end of the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a0a79685093b45c5aaa4e420189bc5c)**:

```
col_1            | col_1_new
:--------------- | :--------
978568-16258     | 16258    
ERGF99252697     | 52697    
SP-988824-189241 | 89241    
SP-456790-568723 | 68723    
SP-456790-568    | 568
```

Comment: This works but the only problem is doesn't work in versions before Mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of MySQL/MariaDB, you can do:

```
select cast(right(col_1,
    (col_1 regexp "[0-9]{1}$") +
    (col_1 regexp "[0-9]{2}$") +
    (col_1 regexp "[0-9]{3}$") +
    (col_1 regexp "[0-9]{4}$") +
    (col_1 regexp "[0-9]{5}$")
) as unsigned) from table_A;
```